# Deploy Sql Changes to Customer Databases (altered tables, functions,...)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I am developing an application that uses a database (either PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle or MSSQL) on the customers system.

Therefore I need to perform database updates with each new version.

I am currently in the concept phase and have nothing running in production.

All the DDL statements are in **script files**.

The structure looks like this:

```
tables\employees.sql
       customers.sql
       orders.sql
```

Those scripts are also in **version control** and can be used to build the database from **stretch**.

Of course there will be changes sometime in the future to those tables.

For example table **employees** gets created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists employees
(
    EmployeeId      serial,
    FirstName       text,

    PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId)
);
```

And in a future release that table gets extended:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN address varchar(30);
```

On my research I found this example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/115422/revisions.
A version number gets used to perform specific changes.

I like that concept and my idea is to implement something similar.
But instead of a system version number I was thinking about introducing a version for each table.

When creating the **employee** table it gets the Version number 1. With each change on that table the version number get increased by 1. After adding the *address column* (alter statement above) the table version would be 2.

Each table change would happen in a nested transaction like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE employees SET Version = 2;

ALTER TABLE employees
     ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN address varchar(30);

END TRANSACTION;
```

If the table version is lower than the current table version the transaction would be rolled back.
The implentation of that logic is yet to be done.

The **benefit** would be that all changes on a table are inside the table's script file itself and the initial statement is always up to date.

For example when first creating the **employee** table it would look like this:

**employees.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists employees
(
    EmployeeId      serial,
    FirstName       text,

    Version         int       default 1 not null,

    PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId)
);
```

After some changes it looks like this:

**employees.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists employees
(
    EmployeeId      serial,
    FirstName       varchar(100),
    address         varchar(80),

    Version         int       default 3 not null, -- notice the 3 

    PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId)
);

-- First Change
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE employees SET Version = 2;

ALTER TABLE employees
    ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN address varchar(30);

END TRANSACTION;

-- Second Change
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE employees SET Version = 3;

ALTER TABLE employees
    ALTER COLUMN address TYPE varchar(80),
    ALTER COLUMN FirstName TYPE varchar(100);

END TRANSACTION;
```

Is that concept acceptable or am I reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: In MySQL any DDL command will cause an implicit commit, therefore DDL changes cannot be rolled back. I do not know what's the situation for other dbs

Comment: You are right, https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis

Comment: You're on the right track, but you're missing some things. (For one, the possibility that changes might be applied in the wrong order.) Web frameworks like Ruby on Rails manage these kinds of things through *migrations*. Research on how they do that would save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think setting the version number per table is overkill. Also, it complicates managing the DB and the application. I suggest you add a new table for DB_VersionNumber and add one row in this table for each upgrade. What I have been doing is this:
1) Create a table in DB for database versions (steps)
2) Create a SP that checks this table and runs a DB upgrade step if it does not exist in the table, otherwise the step is skipped.
3) For each and every DB change, add a step in the upgrade script file (which you have already created and added to the source control).

```
Here is the table and the SP:

IF OBJECT_ID (N'DB_Version', N'U') IS  NULL
Begin
    CREATE TABLE [DB_Version](
        [VersionNumber] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
        [CommitTimestamp] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


    ALTER TABLE DB_Version
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_VersionNumber UNIQUE (VersionNumber); 
End

IF OBJECT_ID ( 'NewDBStep', 'P' ) IS NULL 
begin
    Exec ('
    -- ============================================
    -- Description: Applies a new DB upgrade step to the current DB
    -- =============================================
    CREATE PROCEDURE NewDBStep 
        @dbVersion [decimal](18, 2),
        @script    varchar (max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        If not exists (select 1 from DB_Version Where VersionNumber = @dbVersion)
        Begin
            -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
            -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            BEGIN TRY
                Begin tran
                Exec (@script)

                Insert into DB_Version (VersionNumber, CommitTimestamp) Values (@dbVersion, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
                Commit tran

                Print ''Applied upgrade step '' + Cast ( @dbVersion as nvarchar(20))
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                Rollback tran
                Print ''Failed to apply step '' + Cast ( @dbVersion as nvarchar(20))
                Select ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
                ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
                ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
                ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
                ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
                ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
            END CATCH
        End
    END ') ;
End
```

Then, apply your upgrades by calling the SP (the key is that you have to assign a unique step number to each upgrade script:

```
----------------  Add the new steps here
-- Step: 0.01 
-- Adding the MyTableName table if it does not exist. 
Exec NewDBStep 0.01, '
IF OBJECT_ID (N''MyTableName'', N''U'') IS  NULL
Begin
    CREATE TABLE [MyTableName](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [UserType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
End
'
Exec NewDBStep 1.00, '
-- Some other DDL script 
'
```